# How to add fields to my Application Tabs?

Tags: salesforce1-app, picklist, lightning-apps

I just created Application "Time Management",created Objects fields and tabs.
In my Application only Default Id field is visible but I want to make visible all other fields e.g name,city,email e.t.c
[image]

You can see All fields are visble in Detail section.I want to add them in previous screenshot
[image]

Comment: What you seem to really want to do is to add fields (columns) to your sObject list view.

Comment: Hi John,Yes you are right I want to add columns in my list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the gear icon, next to the "Search this list..." input box do you see a menu item that says "Select Fields to Display"? I'm pretty sure that's what you are looking for.

You might want to create a new list view first and experiment with that one before you start making changes to the default "All" list view.

[image: List View controls]

Comment: Thank you very much john it worked.